# How does google docs sharing work?

Tags: real-time, google-docs, sharing

When you start a new project using google docs, you can invite people to collaborate and you can even see what the other people are doing in real time. I'd like to know what technologies are behind that.

Answer (score 1):

check out these 2 technologies:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor